# Changing function pointers after compilation

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, ogre3d

I am using Ogre3 to try to build a Spawner that automatically creates copies of an Enemy and drop them into the world.  In addition to this, I want to save a behavior function so that when the entity is spawned, it will engage in that behavior as soon as it is dropped into the world.  I was wondering if this was possible to be done.  I was entertaining the thought of reassigning function pointers with a signature like this:

void setBehavior(void (*behavior)(Enemy))

and then save the behavior somewhere.  Any ideas how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Read on the 'Strategy' design pattern.

Implementation-wise function pointer may be enough, more usual is to have class hierarchy implementing different strategies and instance of that is passed -- stored in `unique_ptr<IStrategy>` or something similar. `std::function` worth considering too.